# Sending XML information via SOAP in C# with WSDL

Tags: c#, xml, api, soap, wsdl

I am completely new to this, I didn't even know about SOAP let alone WSDL before this, but here we go. My task is to parse some username information from a JSON API, and then send this information back via a SOAP message with WSDL.

I have the first part (for now I have the username just written in the console), I have all usernames.

**Code so far:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri apiUri = new Uri("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/services/comex/v2/uman/users");
    WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(apiUri);

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;

    NetworkCredential networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");

    CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    myCredentialCache.Add(apiUri, "Basic", networkCredentials);

    httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

    string serializedJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    DeserializedJson deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedJson>(serializedJson);

    foreach (var row in deserializedJson.result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.usern);
    }

    responseStream.Close();
    webResponse.Close();
}

public class Result
{
    public string usern { get; set; }
}

public class DeserializedJson
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

I have the WSDL file as a separate file, which I was able to add as a service reference to my project.
I am provided with a url "https://xxxxxxxx.com/Services/Wdx/Wdx.svc/apikey" and an API-key. I am really unsure what to do with these information.
Do I send a SOAP request and include the api key in the body? What about the data package, how do I include the 4 usernames as an XML?

I'm really looking for some general information, while I'm browsing dozens of other sources about how SOAP works as well, but it's really tough to wrap my head around in such a short time (1 day)
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you've been landed in an unenviable position! I would first suggest that you don't worry too much about "SOAP" or "XML" per se; if you've added a service reference to your solution then you should be able to instantiate a client in your code that will be able to take care of the serialisation and formatting for you. If you've added the "XXXXX" service reference, then a class should have been generated called the "XXXXXClient", which will have some operations available that were defined in the WSDL you were given. Hopefully that points you in the right general direction!